# disable only checkboxes which are in same div instead of all

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to disable all `checkboxes` which are in same div when first `checkbox` is checked and enable again if its unchecked.

and its working for me [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/QpAz6/101/)

```
$('.cdls_content_wrapper input:checkbox:first').click(function () {
    alert('HI');
    $('.cdls_content_wrapper').find(':checkbox').slice(1).each(function () {
        if ($('.cdls_content_wrapper input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

but the problem is when i have another same div and click on that div first `checkbox` it do the same for all.

I want to make my function more general instead of specific to only one div.

Comment: why do you use the same ID's for second div's elements? also why you use checkboxes with `label for=""` when you can write label in `<input type="checkbox">Check box title</input>` and also you have a lot of unclosed elements

Comment: I have copy the first div to check this only . surely all other div elements have different Ids but i can't use Ids as they are generated automatically from server control in asp.net

Comment: but you can customize that control in asp.net, can't you?

Comment: @rahularyansharma: take a look at my updated answer; let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.cdls_content_wrapper').find(':checkbox:first').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.cdls_content_wrapper').find(':checkbox').not(this).attr('disabled', this.checked)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YNRue/)

Comment: IN both all check its disable same checkboxes.

Comment: try click on second All instead of second All checkbox checked .

Comment: @rahularyansharma sorry I didn't get you

Comment: just try to click on first checkbox text 'All' instead of checkboxes. you see the difference ..

Comment: @rahularyansharma that's happening because you have duplicate `ids`

Comment: @billyonecan I don't think so because we haven't use Id in jquery selectors, second you can test this fiddle also . and click on 'LOVE' text instead of checkbox . http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/YNRue/6/

Comment: @rahularyansharma **it is because of duplicate ids**

Answer (score 2):

You may add a `class` to `all`checkbox and do it this way:

```
$('.cdls_content_wrapper input:checkbox.all').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('input:checkbox',$(this).closest('tr').siblings()).attr("disabled", true);
    }else{
        $('input:checkbox',$(this).closest('tr').siblings()).attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Sample [fiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/QpAz6/113/)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function out of the handler, like this:

```
function DoWork(TheDiv) {

   var IsFirstChecked;

   TheDiv.find(':checkbox').each(function () {

        if (typeof(IsFirstChecked) !== 'boolean') {
              IsFirstChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
         } else {
              $(this).prop('disabled', IsFirstChecked);
         }
    });
}
```

And then call it from anywhere:

```
$('.cdls_content_wrapper').find('input').click(function () {
    DoWork($(this).closest('table'));
});

$('.SomeOtherClass').find('input').click(function () {
    DoWork($(this).closest('table'));
});
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpAz6/127/)

Also, as per jQuery [documentation](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-), using `.prop()` is a better way to go than using `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate i nailed it this time!

Just paste this :

```
$('.cdls_content_wrapper input:checkbox:first').click(function () {
    alert('HI');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(':checkbox').slice(1).each(function () {
        if ($('.cdls_content_wrapper input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use different class for your checkboxes in both divs

Comment: any reason for such advice ?

Comment: Because you are doing this using class and all your checkboxes have the same class